# Clear the input buffer of a stream socket

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

For a streaming application, when I switch between functions , I need to clear the input buffer. I have tried to do the following, it works but throws exceptions occasionally due to huge size of data pending in the pipeline.
is there an alternative way to do this?

```
private async void ClearBuffer()
{
    try
    {
        DataReader reader = soc.GetReaderStream();
        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        uint count = reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;

        //if (count > 0)
        {
             // TODO Buffer overflow exception
             await reader.LoadAsync(count);
             reader.ReadBuffer(count);
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Will you please also include **exception** you are getting in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question. It makes no sense to "clear" a socket buffer. There is no feasible way to know for sure what's buffered already. You can ask the `DataReader` what it think it is, but there's no way to know that a) that data is all of the data you were waiting for, nor b) that data doesn't include some other data you might actually want to keep.

A socket is a stream of bytes. You really need to read *every single byte*, and make a deliberate decision as to what to do with each byte. You can't just discard bytes indiscriminately and expect for your communications to remain coherent.

Unfortunately, while the above addresses your immediate question (I believe), it most likely does not really solve whatever issue you were trying to solve when you decided to try to "clear the input buffer". You will be best served by presenting *that* issue in a clear, concise manner, explaining exactly what that issue is, what you've already tried to solve it, and what behavior you want to see in a solution.

Comment: At some point of time, I know I don't need any data that are pending in the buffer. So I have to read and ignore those bits to make the buffer empty and then start a fresh communication. Does Datareader.Dispose() do my job? or it will close the StreamSockets OutputStream?

Comment: @JTsunami: "I know I don't need any data that are pending in the buffer" -- how can you know this? It seems unlikely to me that you can (though I can see how you might _think_ you can). In any case, the question as stated is too vague to understand why you think this is possible, never mind a good idea. If you feel the above doesn't address your specific question adequately, you'll need to add a lot more detail to your question.